# how to change image on click of button xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Im having trouble settings images using xaml since C# doesnt want to be friendly and allow me to change images via code itself because of bitmap. so i was learning more about xaml triggers and was wondering how i edit the source property of the image to change as i click on each button?

```
<Page 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:Custom="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" NavigationCacheMode="Enabled"
    x:Class="Phasmaphobia_Editor.Views.WebViewPage"
    Style="{StaticResource PageStyle}"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid x:Name="ContentArea" Margin="0,0,0,0" Loaded="ContentArea_Loaded">
        <Image x:Name="dark_banner" Height="100" Width="216" Margin="32,72,0,0" Source="/Assets/dark.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="6 Tanglewood Dr" Height="42" Width="226" Margin="27,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" >
            <Button.Triggers>
                
            </Button.Triggers>
        </Button>
        <Button Content="10 Ridgeview Ct" Height="42" Width="226" Click="Button_Click" Margin="27,232,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="13 Willow St" Height="42" Width="226" Click="Button_Click_1" Margin="27,283,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="42 Edgefield Rd" Height="42" Width="226" Margin="27,334,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Bleasdale Farmhouse" Height="42" Width="226" Margin="27,385,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Camp Woodwind" Height="42" Width="226" Margin="27,436,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Grafton Farmhouse" Height="42" Width="226" Margin="27,487,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Maple Lodge Campsite" Height="42" Width="226" Click="Button_Click_2" Margin="27,538,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Prison" Height="42" Width="226" Margin="27,589,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Button Content="Brownstone High School" Height="42" Width="226" Click="Button_Click_3" Margin="27,640,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Image x:Name="light_banner" Height="100" Width="216" Margin="32,72,0,0" Source="/Assets/light.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Image Margin="267,72,36,86" Source="{x:Bind imagesource}"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

I tried changing the image via code in C# but i kept getting errors and stuff from bitmap conversions etc so i was really just looking for something that changed the image to something else on each button click.

Comment: Could you please tell me which Image control is the one that you want to change when button click? Generally, you could change it by handing the button click event.

Comment: You could check my answer about how to do this in the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [XAML Behaviors](https://github.com/microsoft/XamlBehaviors). You can add it from nuget by the name of [Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed).

In the following sample code, at the beginning, First.png is shown. Then, if the Button is clicked, it will be replaced with Second.png.

```xml
<Page
    ...
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity">
    <Page.Resources>
        <BitmapImage x:Key="FirstImage" UriSource="/Assets/First.png" />
        <BitmapImage x:Key="SecondImage" UriSource="/Assets/Second.png" />
    </Page.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Button Content="change image">
            <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                    <core:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=target}"
                                               PropertyName="Source"
                                               Value="{StaticResource SecondImage}"/>
                </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
            </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        </Button>
        <Image x:Name="target"
               Source="{StaticResource FirstImage}"/>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Answer (score 0):

> C# doesnt want to be friendly and allow me to change images via code itself because of bitmap

Actually, you could do it in the code behind. You could handle the Button click event to change the source of the Image Controls

If you just want to change the source of `dark_banner` image which you just used path as source, you could do the following.

```
  <Image x:Name="dark_banner" Height="100" Width="216" Margin="32,72,0,0" Source="/Assets/london.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
  <Button Content="6 Tanglewood Dr" Click="Button_Click" Height="42" Width="226" Margin="27,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Code behind:

```
     private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
     BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
     bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/paris.png");
     dark_banner.Source = bitmapImage;
 }
```

If you want to change the source which you used binding as source.

```
     <Button Content="6 Tanglewood Dr" Click="Button_Click" Height="42" Width="226" Margin="27,183,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
 <Image x:Name="TargetImage" Height="100" Width="216" Margin="267,72,36,86" Source="{x:Bind ImageSource,Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

You need to do a little bit more work. You will have to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=net-7.0) to update the binding.

Code behind:

```
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        ImageSource = new BitmapImage();
        ImageSource.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/paris.png");
    }

    private BitmapImage _imagesource;
    public BitmapImage ImageSource 
    {
        get
        { 
        return _imagesource; 
        }

        set 
        {
            _imagesource = value;
            RaisePropertyChange(nameof(ImageSource));
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    public void RaisePropertyChange(string name) 
    {
        this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name)); ;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapImage.UriSource = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/london.png");
        ImageSource = bitmapImage;
    }
}
```